# Накладные расходы на поддержку tcp соединения

Tags: tcp, производительность

Какие ресурсы (оперативная память, ЦП и тд...) и в каком кол-ве в среднем тратятся на поддержку tcp соединения? Интересны затраты, если соединение в разных состояниях. В итоге хотелось бы увидеть реальные цифры. Какими утилитам в Linux это можно посмотреть?

Comment: Одно дело - расход ресурсов ОС. Другое дело - расход ресурсов самого процесса сервера, который обслуживает соединение. Второе полностью зависит от реализации этого сервера.

Comment: Про реализацию сервера ясно - эти расходы зависят от того на каком языке, и какими гениями писался сервер. Интересен именно расход операционной системой.

Comment: несколько байт на дескриптор

Comment: @Etki: Кем и когда это подсчитано?

Comment: На поддержку соединения копейки, если данные не пересылаются.

Comment: Минимальный размер tcp пакета - 20 байт. Данные на поддержку соединения пересылаются, по истечению времени установленному для keep-alive таймера (это в состоянии established например) По умолчанию интервал -  2 часа.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/8646190/2908793

Comment: Да, пожалуй автор того ответа по ссылке в чем то прав. Правда с чего он взял что sk_buff только один на коннект и какое отношение он вообще имеет к соединению я не понял. sk_buff структура обслужавающая движение пакета между службами ядра. И еще на коннект будет использоваться запись conntrack, если он включен